# Reading the table data from Excel and displaying the number of unique combination of columns in Java

Tags: java, selenium, apache-poi

Suppose I have an excel table as follows:
[Sample Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gQau6.png)

Java program should read the table and compute the result as follows:

No of Column2 type of C1: 2, they are 2 and 1

No of Column3 type of C1: 2, they are 3 and 4

No of Column4 type of C1: 1, that is 4

I could read the excel file contents using Apache POI. Please let me know how to processes the data, Should I use Hashmap ? If possible plese help me with sample code.

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented code using Hashmap with string and list, it is working as expected